# Testing image operations that produce slightly different images

Tags: image, testing, image-processing

Our software performs image operations (for example rotation, deskew etc) and we would like to create unit tests for those. However the operations are not guaranteed to always produce the same result at the byte level. Some noise here and there, some artifacts or dithering might change the result image in a way not apparent to the human eye but breaking a per byte comparison. What would be the best way to test the results of such an operation (assuming I have a reference 'expected image')?

Comment: Maybe you could use a [Delta-E test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIELAB_Delta_E.2A)?

Comment: There is no reason for rotation or skew to be non-deterministic. If you're getting different results every time, no matter how small, you might be reading out of bounds, thereby introducing randomness into your operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automated unit tests do not lend themselves to process which are not deterministic.

Is there any way that you can extract the elements of your code that introduce non-deterministic behaviour, perhaps providing a deterministic implementation in your tests? Or, maybe you can turn the transformation into a pipeline of different transformations, some deterministic and some not.

It sounds like the only thing that can decide if the images "look the same" is a human eye.

An alternative approach would be so have some incredibly simple images which always produce the same result, and use those in unit tests.

Whichever approach you choose (either make the transformations deterministic or relax your equals comparison) I recommend writing some code that produces a report of all the expected and actual images, side by side, in a format that is easy for humans to quickly review.

Comment: "Automated unit tests do not lend themselves to process which are not deterministic."

This covers question

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just take the difference from the expected image to the produced image on a per pixel level? I.e. just subtract the expected RGB values of each pixel from the produced RGB values.

Comment: I'm talking about Unit tests here so I'm looking for an equals type of comparison

Comment: If all you need to do is compare if the two images are equal then just analyze the images pixel by pixel. If any pair of pixels (one from reference and one from produced image) differs by some margin, then you can say the two images are not the same. 

For example, if I had to do this after the software performed the image operation, I would load the reference image and the produced image into MATLAB and do a simple pixel by pixel comparison. I'm sure you could also just simply use "==" to determine equality. If this isn't what you're looking for, then I'm not sure I understand your answer.